# Greengrass deployment fails because Core Version '1.10.2' is below minimum required version: '1.11.0', but '1.11.0' doesn't even exist yet?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-iot, aws-iot-greengrass

> [2020-07-30T19:59:06.34-04:00][ERROR]-Deployment
> failed.   {"deploymentId": "1757359b-c455-4275-ae82-2da19b10a925",
> "errorString": "Greengrass deployment error: unable to execute
> download step in deployment. error while downloading: error occurred
> while getting deployment: GetWithHeaders
> https://greengrass-ats.iot.us-east-2.amazonaws.com:8443/greengrass/groups/2383d3c7-d433-4275-9621-71f9105dbf46/deployments/1757359b-c455-4275-ae82-2da19b10a925,
> statusCode: 400 Bad Request, error: {\n  "code" :
> "IncompatibleGGCVersionException",\n  "message" : "Greengrass
> Core Version '1.10.2' is below minimum required version:
> '[1.11.0]'"\n}"}

Trying to run my first deployment in AWS IOT Greengrass to a group with a Raspberry Pi 3+ core, got a test lambda in there and whenever I hit deploy, I get this error in the logs:

Greengrass Core Version '1.10.2' is below minimum required version: '[1.11.0]'

I've run the OTA update (what a pain to set up) and it completes the job successfully with this in the output:

> [download_artifact]: Executing command: wget -T 30 -q -O /greengrass/ota/ota_agent_v1.2.0/packages/artifact.tar.gz "https://us-east-2-greengrass-updates.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/core/raspbian/armv7l/greengrass-core-raspbian-armv7l-1.10.2.tar.gz

So the update job pulls down 1.10.2.  I looked everywhere and can't see any documentation that 1.11.0 even exists.  I checked the download page and it also only has 1.10.2 as the latest core version available.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/greengrass/latest/developerguide/what-is-gg.html#gg-core-download-tab

I'm pretty confused here, is there any way to disable the check at least so I can deploy what I have?  I'm very new at this AWS Greengrass stuff and it's been quite the effort to get to this point already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your test lambda is on Python3.8 , please try to create it as Python3.7 and redeploy..  Greengrass doesn't support Python3.8